# SQL Server 2008 - T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want a SQL query that determines if a row with specific value exists in `Table1`, or `Table2`, or both

Here is what I wrote, but it is only giving me the values exists in the first table, but not if it is exists in the second table, but not in the first one. I want the results to show exactly as my above statement.

```
  SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Offerid 
                      FROM   dbo.OfferLocations
                      EXCEPT 
                      SELECT Offerid 
                      FROM   dbo.OfferLocUpdate) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0
       END
```

Comment: What's your comparison criteria?

Comment: i want the offerid to show in the results if it is exists in first tabl or second table or both

Comment: I comparing based on the locationid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, like below:

```
;
WITH    OfferLocations AS   -- Sample data, ignore it
        (   SELECT  OfferId
            FROM    ( VALUES (1), (2), (3) ) OfferLocations(OfferId)
        ),
        OfferLocUpdate AS   -- Sample data, ignore it
        (   SELECT  OfferId
            FROM    ( VALUES (2), (3), (4) ) OfferLocUpdate(OfferId)
        )
SELECT      ISNULL(OfferLocations.OfferId, OfferLocUpdate.OfferId) OfferId,
            CASE WHEN OfferLocations.OfferId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [ExistsAtOfferLocations],
            CASE WHEN OfferLocUpdate.OfferId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [ExistsAtOfferLocUpdate]
FROM        OfferLocations
FULL OUTER JOIN OfferLocUpdate
            ON  OfferLocations.OfferId = OfferLocUpdate.OfferId
ORDER BY    ISNULL(OfferLocations.OfferId, OfferLocUpdate.OfferId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try UNION instead of EXCEPT? This will get the distinct Offerid's out of the two tables `dbo.OfferLocations` and `dbo.OfferLocUpdate`.

```
SELECT CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Offerid 
                  FROM   dbo.OfferLocations
                  UNION
                  SELECT Offerid 
                  FROM   dbo.OfferLocUpdate) THEN 1 
     ELSE 0
   END
```